# SSIS Package Deployment Fails using Windows Auth across domains

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Trying to deploy a package on my local PC and connected to my client's vpn.

I get the error:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn>dtutil /File c:\www\clients\SomeCompany\ssis\warehouse\Warehous
e_Update_Table1.dtsx /DestServer SomeServerName /Copy sql;Warehouse_Update_Table1
Microsoft (R) SQL Server SSIS Package Utilities
Version 10.50.1600.1 for 64-bit


Error (0xC0014014) while checking for the existence of package "Warehouse_Update_Table1" on SQL Server.
Could not save package "Warehouse_Update_Table1" because of error 0x80004005.
Description: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
Source: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0

    c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn>dtutil /File c:\www\clients\SomeCompany\ssis\warehouse\Warehouse_Update_Table1.dtsx /DestServer SomeServerName.SomeDomain.net /Copy s
    ;Warehouse_Update_TestTable1
    c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn>dtutil /File c:\www\clients\SomeCompany\ssis\tmlwarehouse\Warehouse_Update_Table1.dtsx /DestServer/SomeServerName.SomeDomain.net /Copy sql;Warehouse_Update_Table1

(obviously I have real values for "SomeCompany" and SomeServerName.SomeDomain"
```

is there a way to elevate rights such as what you can do with an .exe to specify the domain of the sender or to elevate this request so this thing works?

we are calling this using windows auth unfortunately because that's what the client ants.

Comment: Permissions issues like this are why I stopped trying to use SSIS packages to do anything.  I found I could accomplish the same tasks without SSIS (using either straight SQL and batch files, or a C# app if it was more complicated) and it took me less time and was less prone to these types of issues.  Not a fan of SSIS packages at all.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at using runas with the netonly option:

`runas.exe /netonly /user:DOMAIN\DOMAINUSERNAME Dtutil.exe`

It is "DTUtil.exe"